# Remove everything after last forward slash in Google Sheets with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, google-sheets

I have a URL within a Google Sheet that I need to remove everything after the last forward slash in the URL. I also need to ensure that last forward slash is in place and add it, if it is not present.

http://example.com/dp/tt560/?tag=ukos20

http://example.com/dp/tt560/

Can this be wrapped all into one function in Google Sheets?

Here is something which is close, but not a match

I think =REGEXREPLACE could be the formula solution, but I find Regex pretty tricky.

EXAMPLE IN GOOGLE SHEET

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n9H6rbhrHLQP0MSzcGWXjQAah3IkzsS9AQFErYE4SdI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Clarify the last sentence please.

Comment: Try `=REGEXREPLACE(B4, "/[^/]*$", "/")` or with `"/[^/]*/?$"`. Actually, your last example is unclear, since there is a `/` in the string.

Comment: Wiktor, I have fed your suggestion into the example Google Sheet. Looks good to me, please double check the sheet and if you wish to put enter this as an answer I will tick it if you confirm all is good. Thankyou very much.

Comment: Wait, maybe `=REGEXREPLACE(B4, "(/[^/]+)(?:/\?[^/]*)?$", "$1/")` will be better.

Comment: 2nd edit looks spot on, perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1, "(/[^/]+)(?:/\?[^/]*)?$", "$1/")
```

**Details**

- `(/[^/]+)` - Capturing group 1: `/` and then 1+ chars other than `/`
- `(?:/\?[^/]*)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching

  - `/`  - a slash
  - `\?` - a `?` char
  - `[^/]*` - 0 or more chars other than `/`
- `$` - end of string.

The replacement is `$1`, the contents of Group 1 and a `/` that must be present (**adding it where it is missing**).